# What does $f(x)^2$ mean?

Tags: functions, notation

Can anybody tell what $f(x)^2$ means? Is it $f(x^2)$, $(f(x))^2$, or something else?

Comment: It is almost certainly the latter: $(f(x))^2$. Sometimes people also write $f^2(x)$, which is the notation I generally prefer.

Comment: The exponent cannot cross the parenthesis.

Comment: Do be cautious about $f^2(x)$ as it is unclear whether that is meant to be $(f(x))\cdot (f(x))$ or if it is meant to be $f(f(x))$.  Similarly, $f^{-1}(x)$ whether it is the multiplicative inverse $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ or if it is the functional inverse $f^{-1}$ such that $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$.  Examples of each exist in common literature.

Comment: Sometimes $f^2(x)$ can be understood as $f(f(x))$. So it really depends on the context.
Here I would definitely choose $(f(x))^2$.

Comment: It depends - different authors use different notations. I would, however, rule $f(x^2)$ out. It could mean $(f^2)(x)$ or $(f(x))^2$.